# Django | update requirements.txt automatically after installing new package

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, requirements.txt

I am new to Django.

Every time I install new library using `pip`, I have to run `pip freeze -l > requirements.txt` and sometimes I forget this ( and error happens at my production environment).

What's the best way to run this command automatically when I install new packages...?

I am using:

```
Django==1.11.5 
Python 3.6.1
```

Comment: Have you considered using a shell script that already includes the `pip freeze` command after your library installation? You could pass the library name as a command-line argument to your custom script.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to write the script for that and `set a cron job` which will perform this action.

**Not the same thing but a better one**, you can have a look on, [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs)

Comment: @Aoi_777 did it helped?? or you need to know more

Comment: @Aoi_777, feel privileged to help you.

Answer (score 4):

For Python 3 use below to update requirements.txt file.
'''
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
'''